# Swiping Recycler View removes swiped Item but adds last item again

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, swipe

I have an activity,on its creation i am creating five files and then reading those files and adding to my recyclerview. I am also adding swipe functionality to my recyclerview. When an item is swiped, it removes the cell of the recycler view at that position and also deletes the files which i created. The problem which i am facing is Suppose there are five items 1,2,3,4 and 5 in my recyclerview and i swiped to delete 1,the file containing 1 gets deleted but in my recyclerview 5 is added again as soon as i swipe 1. Same thing happens with 2,3 and 4. 5 keeps getting added as soon as a cell is swiped.

Following is my code

```
public class MyRecordingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecordingsAdapter recordingsAdapter;
    private ArrayList<Recording>  recordingArrayList;
    private File userRecordingFile;
    private static final String USER_MIX_DIR = "UserMix";
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList;


    ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback simpleItemTouchCallback = new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {

        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int swipeDir) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Removed"+viewHolder.getAdapterPosition(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();

            recordingsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);

            File file= new File(getExternalCacheDir() +"/"+ USER_MIX_DIR);
            file=new File(file.getAbsolutePath(),"/Recording" + String.valueOf(position-1) + ".txt");
            file.delete();
        }
    };

    ItemTouchHelper itemTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(simpleItemTouchCallback);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_recordings);

        for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
            try{
                userRecordingFile = new File(createRecordingFiles(), "Recording"+i+".txt");
                FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(userRecordingFile);
                writer.append("DEF"+i+"__HIJ "+i+"__\n");
              //  writer.append("R.drawable.ic_launcher\nDEF"+i+"\nHIJ "+i);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        recordingArrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        recyclerView=findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        itemTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
        readFiles();

        recordingArrayList.clear();

       // if(arrayList.get(0)!=null && arrayList.get(1)!=null){
            recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,arrayList.get(0),arrayList.get(1)));
        //}
       // if(arrayList.get(2)!=null && arrayList.get(3)!=null){
            recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,arrayList.get(2),arrayList.get(3)));
       // }
       // if(arrayList.get(4)!=null && arrayList.get(5)!=null){
            recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,arrayList.get(4),arrayList.get(5)));
        //}
        //if(arrayList.get(6)!=null && arrayList.get(7)!=null){
            recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,arrayList.get(6),arrayList.get(7)));
        //}
        //if(arrayList.get(8)!=null && arrayList.get(9)!=null){
            recordingArrayList.add(new Recording(R.drawable.ic_launcher,arrayList.get(8),arrayList.get(9)));
        //}

        recordingsAdapter=new RecordingsAdapter(recordingArrayList);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(recordingsAdapter);
    }



    public  File createRecordingFiles() {

        File dirRoot = getExternalCacheDir();

        File workDir = new File(dirRoot, USER_MIX_DIR);
        Log.i("Hello", "createRecordingFiles: "+workDir);
        if (!workDir.exists()) {
            workDir.mkdirs();

        }
        return workDir;
    }


    public void readFiles(){
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br=null;
        try {
            File dirRoot = getExternalCacheDir();
            File workDir = new File(dirRoot, USER_MIX_DIR);

            for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
                File file = new File(workDir,"Recording"+i+".txt");

                br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String line;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    text.append(line);

                  //  text.append('\n');
                    arrayList=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(text.toString().split("__")));
                   // Toast.makeText(this, ""+arrayList.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
            br.close() ;
        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to refresh the adapter by `norifyDataSetChanged` method

Comment: I had added the notifyDataSetChanged , but then swipe functionality misbehaves. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: you need to update the data set that is connected to the adapter and then call notifyDataSetChanged.. do you do that?

Comment: Just split your problem into subproblems and try to test which part is not working (deleting the file , refreshing the list ..).

ps: file.delete returns a boolean (true if the file is really deleted)

Comment: @Darko I did that

Comment: @HamzaElmi File do get deleted

Comment: I can see that your are not deleting the item from the arraylist before calling notifyItemRemoved.

Comment: @HamzaElmi i am confused how to remove items from my arraylist. Suppose user swipes item at position 2, i need to remove items present at 2 and 3. I can't write if statements for each Cell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `Adapter.notifyItemRemoved(x)` will not do anything if you don't remove the item from the List attached to your adapter.

```
final int position = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
recordingArrayList.remove(position);
recordingsAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
```

Comment: recordingArrayList.remove(position); ?
what do you mean by you cannot use it directly ?

Comment: Thanks alot. I got confused between the two array list which i have defined